# How do you change the path to the images folder in Mediawiki?

Tags: openshift, mediawiki

I have a Mediawiki installation on openshift, so everything inside the app-root/repo/ folder gets deleted whenever I update via git push.  My image folder is in app-root/repo/wiki/images

[Openshift](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-filesystem.html#__code_data_code) also provides a persistent data/ folder, so how can I set the images folder to be in data e.g. in app-root/data/images/ ?

Comment: Did you try https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUploadDirectory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a symlink to your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR using an action hook like this: https://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy

Comment: Thank you.  How do I run the action hook?

Comment: It will run automatically when you deploy your application (make sure it is chmod +x), and make sure you commit it to your git repo.